# Scrollbar - make it visible by mobile device MUI React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, scrollbar

I want to make my scrollbar always visible if there is an overflow. I achieved it using this code in my `Apps.css` For the styles I am using Material UI 5 (MUI). However, the problem is when I change to mobile view with Brave or another browser the scroll appears only when I start to scroll and it is no the color I have set, but it's default grey scrollbar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #26b640 !important;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  width: 8px !important;
}
```

I tried to modify my code by adding and playing with these properties but haven't achieved the desired result

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
-webkit-appearance: none;
overflow:auto;
}
```